# certificates with SDK tools (makecert, pvk2pfx)

Tags: certificate, pfx, makecert

I need to make two certificates: CA sert and Server cert.

I use this commands.

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CACert" -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority -sv CACert.pvk CACert.cer

certutil -addstore Root TGCA.cer

makecert -pe -n "CN=ServerCert" -a sha1 -sky exchange -ic CACert.cer -iv CACert.pvk -sv ServerCert.pvk ServerCert.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk ServerCert.pvk -spc ServerCert.cer -pfx ServerCert.pfx
```

Then I import ServerCert.pfx to certificate storage.

Why they do not contain private key in storage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you try to generate pfx file by passing the private key password as an argument?

Try it this way

```
pvk2pfx -pvk ServerCert.pvk -spc ServerCert.cer -pfx ServerCert.pfx -pi password
```

As the documentation says:

/pi pvkpassword
Specifies the password for the .pvk file.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, the pvk2pfx tool is somewhere like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86

Answer (score 1):

So, after a long dance with a tambourine I found a solution. Problem was in UI. My goal was to import pfx to localmachine storage. It's impossible to do by starting pxf file from folder.

When pxf imports wihout pvk pass, the internal private key do not imports. Password do not requests when importing to localmachine storage by MMC.

What I made:

1. Import pxf-file from file explorer to CurrentUser "My" strorage (entering pvk password).
2. Export certificate from storage to new pxf with password.
3. Import new pxf to localmachine "My" storage with MMC.

I don't know other ways.